# php call anonymous functions inside anonymous function

Tags: php, closures

Php version : 5.4

```
function foo(callable $succCallback) {

        $isCallable = is_callable($succCallback);
        echo "is callable outer ".is_callable($succCallback);
        $success = function($fileInfo) {
            echo "<br>is callable inner".is_callable($succCallback);
        };
        $this->calllll($success);
}
function calllll(callable $foo) {
  $foo("hello");
}
```

I define a function like that

And the output is

```
is callable outer 1
is callable inner
```

How can I refer to the `$succCallback` inside `$success`'s body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `use` construct. It allows to inherit variables from the parent scope:

```
function foo(callable $succCallback) {

        $isCallable = is_callable($succCallback);
        echo "is callable outer ".is_callable($succCallback);
        $success = function($fileInfo) use($succCallback) {
            echo "<br>is callable inner".is_callable($succCallback);
        };
        $this->calllll($success);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$success = function ($fileInfo) use ($succCallback) {
    echo "<br>is callable inner" . is_callable($succCallback);
};
```

To include variables from the surrounding scope inside anonymous functions, you need to explicitly extend their scope using `use ()`.

Answer (score 2):

To use variables from the parent scope, use `use`:

```
 $success = function($fileInfo) use ($succCallback) {
        echo "<br>is callable inner".is_callable($succCallback);
    };
```